# Prediction interval in nnetar forecast

Tags: prediction-interval

I'm trying to use the forecast package version 5.6 for doing forecasts with "nnetar" function, so I noticed that there's no prediction intervals for forecasting points by this function, eg.: 95% LS and LI.
Does someone could help me about how to compute confidence intervals for forecasts based on "nnetar"?

Note: I have used ets and auto.arima functions to perform linear univariate time series forecasts, but in some situations I have also some non-linear time series and I'd like to use neural nets as an optional tool.

Comment: What does `nnetar` purport to do?  As it is currently worded, this question is so dependent on understanding this one particular software package that it seems more of a programming question than a statistical one.